# Why does "My Documents" on old Windows 7 install drive letter X: point to "My Documents" on C:

Tags: windows-7, my-documents

I'm throwing away an old computer and removed the drive from it to repurpose it. I have some saved data in My Documents. When I mounted the drive onto my main computer, surprise, the My Documents folder now points to the folder on C: drive (C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents) instead of opening it on X: where I have assigned the old drive.

X:\Users\MYUSER\Documents is almost empty, just the default stuff (music, pictures, videos, all empty).
X:\Users\MYUSER\My Documents, which is a link, points to my C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents.

Maybe this confusion is generated by the fact that my username is the same. To try to work around it, I renamed the Users folder to UsersA and my username too. It didn't help. The X:\User\Documents folder is empty.

As this is an old Windows 7, I'm quite sure I didn't encrypt my home folder, not even sure if it was possible in this version of Windows :D.

Do you think that simply by mounting this drive on another computer Windows wiped some information located on the other drive? Kind of doubt it, since I didn't do any writing on that drive.

I also tried using an "undelete" software to try and dig in the file system. It's empty there as well. And I'm absolutely sure this shouldn't be so. I had stuff there.

Comment: You hooked old hard drive to a machine where Windows 10 is installed, right?

Comment: You’ve pretty much answered your own questions. My documents is a link that is confusing, ignore it. And the documents folder is nearly empty. If it’s empty it’s empty. Either you’re browsing the wrong user folder or the data wasn’t there to begin with. It didn’t get erased by simply mounting the drive.

Comment: @Alex no, it's another W7 machine.

Comment: If you still have old comp, reconnect old drive back and after loading, in Windows Explorer, make a right click on `Documents` for example and choose `Property`, you will see where real location of `Document` folder. It can point to anywhere besides of default locations, to a network drive for example.